# Anchor links with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, twitter-bootstrap-3, apache2

I am doing some url rewriting with .htaccess in front of a php site.

The relevant rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^tests$ /test.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tests/([a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$) /test.php?test=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tests/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ /test.php?test=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

This is working fine when accessing the page with /tests/parameter1 but when accessing the page with /tests/parameter1/parameter2 the anchor(#) links on my page
stops working. I am using bootstrap tabs

```
<li><a href="#add" data-toggle="tab">.....
<li><a href="#remove" data-toggle="tab">.....
```

so when accessing the page with one parameter it works, but when accessing the page with 2 parameters the tabs stops working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using [QSA,L] instead of [L] your rewrite rule?

Comment: Yes I have, but with no luck...

Comment: @TheG Does the anchor `#` appends in url?

Comment: @RahilWazir yes, it appends to the url when clicking on the link. This works: /tests/parameter1#anchor this doesn't work /tests/parameter1/parameter2#anchor

Comment: Tested you config on my site. Your config seems to be correct: You can test it running here: [link](http://www.malmanger.no/tests/paramA/paramB)

Comment: @TheG First the `#` should not have to append in url, if so please see the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage) to prevent the `#` append to url using `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: that's weird... On my page all the tabs shows up one after another....

Comment: Since it doesn't seem to be a problem in your .htaccess, I would guess it's a HTML/JS bootstrap problem?

Comment: Found it... I had an unclosed html tag which messed up everything. Thank you guys :)